# Sitemap not working

Tags: wordpress, seo

I am using a wordpress site, when I add a sitemap to webmaster tools I get 2 errors;

Error 1
We encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please ensure your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the location you provided and then resubmit.

URL restricted by robots.txt

Error 2
Sitemap is HTML
Your Sitemap appears to be an HTML page. Please use a supported sitemap format instead.

I am using the all in seo plugin, the sitemap prefix is 'sitemap'
I have also added my google verification into the box in settings page as: google-site-verification=La3IH5EIdWJcJa4uUYWmt6vMkeHK3SsazrZ1KBqkdh8

I am not sure where the robots.txt file is?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming


Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ISSUE 1**
*URL restricted by robots.txt*
This means that when google's 'spiders' tries to index your sitemap they were blocked by your sitemap. You can either remove the file if you're not using it or make sure that your not blocking the sitemap or even worse the whole site from being indexed.
 **The following robots.txt would prevent all crawlers from indexing the entire site:**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

**Simply remove the trailing slash to prevent such an instance like such:**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

**ISSUE 2**
*Error 2 Sitemap is HTML Your Sitemap appears to be an HTML page. Please use a supported sitemap format instead.*

Firstly, HTML sitemaps are useful for end-users, and search engine spiders in some cases, but for your official sitemap Google insists on it being formatted in XML.

Hers an example of the markup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

<url>

    <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>

    <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>

    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>

    <priority>0.8</priority>

</url>
```

Moreover, if you're site is enormous or you can't be bothered to manually create the site map there are some decent online sitemap generators.

Such as:
http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/
http://www.sitemapdoc.com/

Comment: I remove robots.txt and then works!! Thank you ;-)